# Rails get title

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How can I get the title of my page using Rails? `content_for` will set it, so is there a better way than to assign it to an instance variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your'e using `content_for` to set it, you can simply use `content_for` to get it as well.

```
<% content_for :title, "My Title" %>

Some time later ... 
<title><%= content_for :title %></title>
...
<h1><%= content_for :title %></h1>
```